# Pulling data from many excel files all into another file?

Tags: excel, vba, while-loop

I've looked at quite a bit of questions on here on pulling data from excel files into another but I can't seem to figure it out. I think it might have something to do with using Dir to define file, since when I check the value of file it returns nothing.

```
Sub PullFromRunsheets()


Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Dim MyObj As Object, MySource As Object, file As Variant, a As String, columnItertor As Integer

file = Dir("c:\Desktop\Runsheets\")
While (file <> "")
columnIterator = 0
  If InStr(file, "Runsheet") > 0 Then ''If the string "Runsheet" appears at least once in the filename...
     '' What to do if the file found contains the string "Runsheet"?            MsgBox "found " & file
     '' Take the value in cell B7 of the runsheet file and put it in cell A5 of the current file.
     For rowIterator = 0 To 7

            a = Workbooks(file).Worksheets("Pacman Runsheet").Cells(7, 2 + rowIterator).Value '' Set "a" = whatever value is in B7, and iterate through that row
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet1).Cells(5 + rowIterator, 1).Value = a ''take that value and put it in this column, iterate through.

     Next rowIterator

     Exit Sub




  End If
  '' columnIterator = columnIterator + 1 (ignore this for now)

 file = Dir
Wend

End Sub
```

I'm essentially trying to pull data from every file inside of a given folder that has "Runsheet" in its filename, and place that data into the current workbook that the macro was written in. When I run the code I get no errors, however nothing happens at all which is why I don't know where I went wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: `Exit Sub` remove that. the very first time  you find a `*Runsheet*` file you exit the proc. Always Use `F8` to debug .

Comment: Indeed, remove Exit Sub

Comment: @cyboashu I removed it however I'm still struggling to get the code to actually do anything when it runs.

Answer (score 0):

have fun with it ;)

```
Sub PullFromRunsheets()

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim currentFile As Variant, baseDirectory, filterKeyword, sourceWorksheetName, sourceRange, targetWorksheetName As String, targetStartRow, targetColumnIterator As Integer

baseDirectory = "c:\Desktop\Runsheets\"
filterKeyword = "Runsheet"
sourceWorksheetName = "Pacman Runsheet"
sourceRange = "B7:B14"
targetWorksheetName = "Sheet1"
targetStartRow = 5
targetColumnIterator = 1

currentFile = Dir(baseDirectory)
While (currentFile <> "")
  If InStr(currentFile, filterKeyword) > 0 Then
     Workbooks.Open baseDirectory + currentFile
        Workbooks(currentFile).Worksheets(sourceWorksheetName).Range(sourceRange).Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(targetWorksheetName).Cells(targetStartRow, targetColumnIterator).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
     Workbooks(currentFile).Close
     targetColumnIterator = targetColumnIterator + 1
  End If
  currentFile = Dir
Wend

End Sub
```